# How to update column values in the first N rows of a table in PostgreSQL without having a primary key on the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL and I have a table where I need to update the values of a specific column in the first N rows with the value of a sequence. However, the table does not have a primary key (I tried to use `ctid` instead).

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this in PostgreSQL?

I need a query that allows me to target the first N rows reliably without relying on a primary key constraint. I have 50+ million rows in the table, so only updating in batches will work.

The order does not matter.

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried to use *ctid*, but it takes a long time to change even 1 value because it goes row-by-row and compares the id, which is not optimal.

```sql
WITH ttrows AS 
(
    SELECT ctid 
    FROM test_table 
    LIMIT 1
)
UPDATE test_table tt
SET temp_id = nextval('test_table_temp_id_seq')
FROM rows 
WHERE tt.ctid = ttrows.ctid;
```

I would like to have a solution what goes row-by-row and does the update in-place because the order is not important for me.

Comment: Please update your question with the full DDL for the table - including any indexes. If you don't have any index then any query you run is going to require a full table scan - which will be slow

Comment: This is just a test_table with 10 columns without indexes. I'll actually have to do the same thing on several tables, but none of them will have an index.

Comment: If you want to update the records in batches then either you need to record which records have been updated (so you can exclude them from the next run) or you need to use a range of values in a particular column (or group of columns) to define each batch. However, if you have no indexes then each query will run a full table scan and therefore be slow

Comment: How do you define "in the first N rows"? Tables rows do not have inherent ordering.

Comment: I meant the first N rows the query returns. The order does not matter. The goal is to update the column in batches.

Comment: Why not just use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: If I create an auto_increment (SERIAL) column it locks the whole table for ~10 minutes.

Comment: Only when you create it, then you avoid the performance and locking issues forever (the ones where you keep doing a `LIMIT 1` query to get the last ID). Just take a maintenance window and take the DB offline.